# GraphQL use an object type from a file in another file

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma

Guys I want to do something like that, but I cant find the answer. I want to be able to use an object type defined in one file, inside another file.

```
**post.schema.ts**

type Post{
name:String!
}


**user.schema.ts**

type User{
name:String!
posts:[Post!]
}
```

Comment: Can you add more information so that people can understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Have you tried `# import Post from "./post.schema.graphql"`?

Comment: It says: "Invalid character." when I use "#" and it's a typescript file not graphql. I've created a schema file and a resolver file for each entity that I have and at the end I merge them... but I can't use them like this if they have a relation

Comment: What error you get from it?